# How to upload multiple image in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to upload multiple images in a single row in a database table and access them in a show page.I have tried this tutorial:
[laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/](http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/)
but there two different tables are made and a relation is established.

I want this to happen in a single table.

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far

Comment: I am following tutorial : laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4

Comment: Ok. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

here is what worked best for me:

first do this in your form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/details">
```

and this for multiple selection:

```
<input required type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" placeholder="address" multiple>
```

Now do this in your controller:

```
public function store(request $request) {

    $input=$request->all();
    $images=array();
    if($files=$request->file('images')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('image',$name);
            $images[]=$name;
        }
    }
    /*Insert your data*/

    Detail::insert( [
        'images'=>  implode("|",$images),
        'description' =>$input['description'],
        //you can put other insertion here
    ]);


    return redirect('redirecting page');
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: hi i'm wondering how about if i use validation, what should i write? ```$data = $request->validate(['name'=>'required', 'files' => 'file']);``` it kinda work but i'm unable to fetch the file data after that

Comment: something like :

       $this->validate($request, [
            'files' => 'array|required',
            'files.*' => 'required|mimetypes:image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/bmp'
        ]);

Comment: Working Awesome Brother

Answer (score 3):

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{URL::to('addimage')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 15px">                            
         <label class="col-lg-3">Upload</label>
         <input class="btn btn-primary"  type="file" name="files[]" > <br/>
    </div>
</form>




$images = $request->file('files');
if ($request->hasFile('files')) :
        foreach ($images as $item):
            $var = date_create();
            $time = date_format($var, 'YmdHis');
            $imageName = $time . '-' . $item->getClientOriginalName();
            $item->move(base_path() . '/uploads/file/', $imageName);
            $arr[] = $imageName;
        endforeach;
        $image = implode(",", $arr);
else:
        $image = '';
endif;



        DB::table('fooo')->insert(
        array(
            'image' => $image
           )
       );

        Session::flash('message', 'Image upload successfully successfully');
        return redirect('/addimage');
```

Answer (score 2):

this can also be achieved with

```php
            foreach ($request->file('files') as $index => $item) {
                $path = $request->files[$index]->store('images');
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me.

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/details">
```

and this for multiple selection image:

```
<input required type="file" class="form-control" name="image[]" placeholder="address" multiple>
```

Now do this in Our Model:

```
protected fillable = ['producd','image', ];
```

Now do this in Our controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $image = array();
  if($file = $request->file('image')){
      foreach($file as $file){
          $image_name = md5(rand(1000,10000));
          $ext = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
          $image_full_name = $image_name.'.'.$ext;
          $uploade_path = 'uploads/images/';
          $image_url = $uploade_path.$image_full_name;
          $file->move($uploade_path,$image_full_name);
          $image[] = $image_url;
      }
      Image::insert([
          'image' => implode('|', $image),
          'producd' => $request->producd,
      ]);
      return redirect('/image.index'));       
  }
}
```

Comment: how to fectch and displpay the Multiple images in index page in laravel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>
```

controller : store folder storage

```
foreach ($request->file('images') as $imagefile) {
   return $imagefile->store('images','public');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $images = array();
    if ($request->hasFile('gallery_image')) {
        $files = $request->file('gallery_image');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $image_name = md5(rand(1000, 10000));
            $ext = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $image_full_name = $image_name . '.' . $ext;
            $file->move('Your image path here', 
            $image_full_name);
            $images[] = $image_full_name;
        }
    }
    $house->gallery_image = json_encode($images);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).