# Product image update

Tags: laravel

I'm unsuccessfully trying to update multiple images with the following code.

- How can I update multiple images?

```
 if (count($request->product_image) > 0) {
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($request->product_image as $image) {       
    if (File::exists('images/products/'.$product->image)) {
        File::delete('images/products/'.$product->image);
    }
    $img = time() . $i .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = 'images/products/' .$img;
    Image::make($image)->save($location);
    $product_image = ProductImage::find($id);
    $product_image->product_id = $product->id;
    $product_image->image = $img;
    $product_image->save();
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: in the line ProductImage::find($id); which is the $id ?? Maybe it doesn't find anything

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I uploded five image. but when i update it only one image delete and update. Other images are not delete and update

Answer (score 0):

this is how i have done in my project.

```
 if ($request->hasFile('destination_images')) {
        foreach ($request->destination_images as $img) {
            $id=$destination->id;
            $image = new DestinationImage; 
            $fileNameWithExt = $img->getClientOriginalName(); //getting extension
            $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filenameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            $path = $img->move('images/destinations', $filenameToStore);

            $image->destination_id=$id;
            $image->name = $filenameToStore;
            $image->save();
        }
```

You can also refer to [How to upload multiple image in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643265/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

That is how i added the multiple images:
My blade file:

```
<form role="form" action="{{route('home.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
     Images
     <input type="file" name="banner[]" class="form-control" id="image" multiple required>
   </div>
</form>
```

The controller store function:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

 if($request->hasfile('banner')) {
  foreach($request->file('banner') as $image){
   $filename=time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $filename);
    $data[] = $filename;
            }
        }
 $property = new Property;
 $property->banner=json_encode($data);
 $property->save();
}
```

Showing images on blade file:

```
@foreach($properties as $property)
 @foreach(json_decode($property->banner, true) as $images)
  <div class="item">
   <img src="{{asset('images')}}\{{$images}}">
  </div>
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Update function:

```
public function updateapartment(Request $request, $id) {
   if($request->hasfile('banner')) {
      $del = Property::findorfail($id);
       $image_path = "images/".$del->banner;  // Value is not URL but directory file path
        if(File::exists($image_path)) {
            File::delete($image_path);
        }
        $del->delete();
      foreach($request->file('banner') as $image){
        $filename=time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $filename);
        $data[] = $filename;
            }
  $up = Property::findorfail($id);
  $up->banner=json_encode($data);
  $up->save();
        }
    }

}
```