# Multiple images upload not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to store multiple images to the database but it only stores one image. I don't see any errors. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643265/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-laravel/42643349) but it stores images in public folder, I want the images to be stored in database. How can I fix this? any help would be appreciated.

Controller

```
   if($request->hasFile('files')){
        $files = $request->file('files');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $images = $file->store('public/photos');
        }
  }

        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' =>  $images
        ]);
```

Blade

```
   <input type="file" name="files[]">
```

Comment: Add `multiple` to input, see if that changes things. Try do `dd($files);` after you set the variable to ese if it actually has multiple items.

Comment: All images are storing to public/photos folder but not storing all image name in database. Is that your problem?

Comment: That hasn't changed things @MatthiasS

Comment: No it only stores one image in database  I don't want images to be stored in the project @Jseelb

Comment: But : `$images = $file->store('public/photos');` this is actually storing the file on the disk. What you are storing in the database is only the path to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one issue on your code, you are moving images correctly but storing it in DB outside of loop, which will only store last iteration of loop in DB, you can use this code to store multiple images in DB

```
if($request->hasFile('files')){

    $store_file = [];
    $files = $request->file('files');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $images = $file->store('public/photos');

        $store_file[] = [

            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' =>  $images
        ];
    }

    ProductsPhoto::insert($store_file);
}
```