# How to upload images as array for updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a column on the database named `image_path` which has data like this:

`Untitled-1.jpg,Untitled-2.jpg`

So as you can see every record have multiple image path and I tried separating them with **,**

Now for updating the pictures, I added this form:

```
@php 
   $paths = explode(",",$popup->image_path);
@endphp 
@for($y=0;$y<=count($paths)-1;$y++)
    @php $counter = $y; @endphp 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="image" class="control-label">Picture {{ ++$counter }}
            </label>
            <br>
            <img src="https://sitename.com/{{ $paths[$y] }}" style="width: 20%;height:50%;" id="image">
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="filep" name="filep[{{ $y }}]">
        </div>
    </div>
@endfor
```

Now at the Controller, I added this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    for($k=0;$k<=count($request->filep);$k++){
        if(!empty($request->filep[$k])){
            $kpop = DB::table('popups')->find($id);
            $image_name = time() . $request->file('filep')[$k]->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/popups');
            $request->file('filep')[$k]->move($destinationPath, $image_name);
            Popup::where('id',$kpop->id)->update(['image_path'=>$kpop->image_path.",".$image_name]);
        }
    }
}
```

And it works correctly but the problem is it adds the image and not replacing the image with the uploaded one.

So how can I properly update images properly?

Comment: If its not to late, refactor your database to use proper normal form and then these queries will be soooooo much easier.

Comment: I think this should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643265/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-laravel/42643349