# Laravel media multi upload

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload multi lessons. But something isn't working. I think there problem with $data->lesson can't get lesson or it's problem with create really don't know i'm new in this : )
Here's my controller

```
public function storeLesson(Lesson $lesson)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'lesson.lesson' => 'required',
            'lesson_folder_id.lesson_folder_id' => '',
        ], [
            'lesson.lesson.required' => 'error message',
        ]);
        if (request()->hasFile('lesson')) {
            $path = request()->file('lesson')->store('lessons', ['disk' =>      'my_files']);
            $data->lesson = $path;
        }


        $create = $lesson->create($data['lesson'],['lesson_folder_id']);

        return redirect('/courses')->with('success', 'success message.');
    }
```

filesystem.php

```
 'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],

        'my_files' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path() . '/'
        ]
    ],
```

And my blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('storeLesson') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="mb-3">
                @foreach($c->lessonFolders as $f)
                {{ $f->name }}
                <input hidden name="lesson_folder_id[lesson_folder_id]" type="text" value="{{ $f->id }}">
                <label class="form-label" for="customFile"></label>
                <input name="lesson[lesson]" type="file" class="form-control" id="customFile">
                @foreach($f->lessons as $l)
                @if($l->lesson)
                TRUE
                @endif
                @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">upload</button>
        </form>
```

So what's i'm doing wrong? it's controller fault or my blade fault ?

Comment: you have to pass an array in the name like `lessons[]` or `lessons[$id]` key should be unique, in above example key is going to be same for all files.

Comment: I changed in blade lessons[] and lesson_folder_id[] still don't work

Comment: When you pass the array you can loop the array and store each array in the database.
use `dd()` to dump values in your controller and check whether you are receiving all the necessary values

Comment: @Vaskontrop you need to change variables in the controller as well because I have posted `lessons` not `lesson`.

Comment: I changed in controllers what was lesson to lessons but it's still don't work

Comment: have a look at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643265/how-to-upload-multiple-image-in-laravel/42643349

Answer (score 0):

if you named `lesson[]` to the input tag, `$request->lesson` will give an array not a file, so you can not use `request()->hasFile('lesson')`

You should use `name="lesson"` for single upload, if you want multi upload you should use `lesson[]` and then in the controller

```
    if (is_array(request()->lesson)) {
        foreach (request()->lesson as $lesson) {
            $path = $lesson->store('lessons', ['disk' => 'my_files']);
            $data->lesson = $path;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changes if with your example but what about course_folder_id ?  and on blades i have lesson_folder_id[] and lessons[] but it don't work

Comment: Nah I see, your code has so many wrong codes.

Comment: Yes i know ( it's hard for me to write good codes because i'm new in this but how can i do it right way ?

Comment: you need to explain what do you want and what doesnt work .

Comment: User must create course folders and he can make it and then in folder he must upload lessons he can upload one lesson then another lesson in different Choose file and if he want he will chose 5 lessons and then he must click submit button and this 5 lessons must upload 5 different records in lessons table course_folder_id will be same with different lessons. sorry for my bad english